# Why won't Google's Cityhash gem install?

Tags: ruby, macos, ffi, murmurhash

I am trying to use Ruby's FFI to attach to the Google cityhash gem; It is a 64 bit, and 128 bit, non-cryptographic hash, similar to the default Ruby hash function (murmur_hash 1), but is a bit more recent, and, more importantly, allows setting the seed on the hash.

I installed cityhash into `/usr/local/lib` using the default `./configure` on my Mac.
This places some libraries in `/usr/local/lib`:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel 13720 Jul 11 15:16 /usr/local/lib/libcityhash.0.dylib
-rw-r--r-- 1 root wheel 43424 Jul 11 15:16 /usr/local/lib/libcityhash.a
lrwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel    19 Jul 11 15:16 /usr/local/lib/libcityhash.dylib -> libcityhash.0.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel   977 Jul 11 15:16 /usr/local/lib/libcityhash.la
```

I am using Mac OS X.
The gcc version is 4.6 which is not the default Mac gcc, but I tried that too.

```
ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18 revision 30909) [x86_64-darwin10.6.0]
```

ffi (installed with default gcc on mac, gcc 4.6 doesn't work?)

I made the simplest module that I could:

```
require 'ffi'
module MyCityHash
  extend FFI::Library

  ffi_lib 'cityhash'
  attach_function  :CityHash64,  [:string, :size_t], :uint64    
end
```

but when I try to include this module into any Ruby class or script file I get the error:

```
/Users/charlesmartin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/ffi-1.0.9/lib/ffi/library.rb:147:in `attach_function': Function 'CityHash64' not found in [libcityhash.dylib] (FFI::NotFoundError)
```

CityHash64 has the signature in city.h:

```
uint64 CityHash64(const char *buf, size_t len);
```

I would greatly appreciate any insight on how to debug this.

Answer (score 3):

From a quick look at the cityhash project, it looks like it is C++, which means they are not visible as C symbols.  The names will be mangled (you can see this if you run 'nm libcityhash.dylib').

You have a couple of choices:

1. Work out what the mangled names are (using nm or objdump), and use them as the native function name to attach_function.  e.g.

   ```
   attach_function :CityHash64, :__Z10CityHash64PKcm, [ :string, :size_t ], :uint64
   ```

   where "__Z10CityHash64PKcm" is the symbol name of of CityHash64 as shown by nm (note: the mangled name differs between platforms).  The first arg to attach_function is the name you want it to be callable as from ruby, so you would still call it as MyCityHash.CityHash64().
2. Expose the cityhash functions as C symbols (and hence visible to ruby-ffi) by prefixing each function you want to access with 'extern "C"'. e.g.

   ```
   extern "C" uint64 CityHash64(const char *buf, size_t len);
   ```

Then rebuild libcityhash.dylib.

If you're creating a gem to distribute to others, then you'll have to use option #1, unless you can convince the cityhash maintainers to expose the functions to plain old C.